# Modify MS ACCESS ImportExportSpecifications

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on trying to import two text documents that are very similar but go into different tables in my db. I referenced the solution referenced on: [How can I modify a saved Microsoft Access 2007 or 2010 Import Specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143420/how-can-i-modify-a-saved-microsoft-access-2007-or-2010-import-specification]), which helped get me to where I am now. I have 2 saved import specs, one for each file, but I am unable to specify which spec I am trying to modify when importing files. The code works great for the file that is picked up but I can't see to get the code to modify the second import spec. The first spec is for "opt" files and second is for "recip" files. Am I missing something?

```
On Error GoTo ERR_Handler:
    Dim mySpec As ImportExportSpecification
    Dim myNewSpec As ImportExportSpecification
    Dim y As Integer, x As Date
    Dim myDir As String, fn As String, a(), n As Long
    Dim RecentFile As String, myDate As Date, temp As Date, strData As String

    myDir = "\\Text Files"
    fn = Dir(myDir & "\Op?" & ".txt") 'Change to myDir & "\XX?" & ".txt" for each file
    x = Date

Do While fn <> ""
temp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(myDir & "\" & fn).DateLastModified
   If myDate = 0 Then
      myDate = temp: RecentFile = myDir & "\" & fn
Else
   If myDate < temp Then myDate = temp: RecentFile = myDir & "\" & fn
End If
fn = Dir

Loop

    For y = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Count - 1
    If CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Item(y).Name = "TemporaryImport" Then
    CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Item("TemporaryImport").Delete
    y = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Count
End If
Next y
    Set mySpec = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Item(myTempTable)
    CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Add "TemporaryImport", mySpec.XML
    Set myNewSpec = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Item("TemporaryImport")

    myNewSpec.XML = Replace(myNewSpec.XML, "RecentFile", myPath)
    myNewSpec.Execute
    myNewSpec.Delete
    Set mySpec = Nothing
    Set myNewSpec = Nothing
exit_ErrHandler:
    For y = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Count - 1
    If CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Item(y).Name = "TemporaryImport" Then
        CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Item("TemporaryImport").Delete
        y = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Count
    End If
    Next y
Exit Sub
ERR_Handler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume exit_ErrHandler
End Sub
```

The code above is identical for the "recip" files, with the exception of `fn = Dir(myDir & "\Op?" & ".txt")` which gets changed to `fn = Dir(myDir & "\recip?" & ".txt")`. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: No, there are no error messages that create. The code works great for modifying and running the last created saved import. But, I can't get the code to modify and run the first saved import steps that are for the other file that I need to import.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but i guess you are trying to import a text file save the steps and use the saved template to import additional files?

so logically your code should be like this:

1. Do an import (append data)
2. save the steps
3. Loop through further files to be imported
4. Change the file path in the savedTemplate
5. import the file > do this until all files have been imported.

in code it would be something like:

```
With CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications("ImportSection-95")

    mSelectedFile = "" 'C:\mytext.txt  or your loop to get the file path..

    If Nz(mSelectedFile, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "! You haven't selected any file this event will be cancelled", vbExclamation, "No source file selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

   'Modify the xml path
    Dim mStart_pos, mEnd_pos As Integer
    Dim mPrevious_text As String

    mStart_pos = VBA.InStr(VBA.InStr(1, .XML, "Path"), .XML, """")
    mEnd_pos = VBA.InStr(mStart_pos + 1, .XML, """ ")

    mStart_pos = mStart_pos + 1
    mPrevious_text = VBA.mID(.XML, mStart_pos, mEnd_pos - mStart_pos)
    Debug.Print "previous path: " & mPrevious_text
    Debug.Print "will be replaced by: " & selectedFile

    .XML = VBA.Replace(.XML, mPrevious_text, mSelectedFile)

End With

'now run the modifieed saved import
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "ImportSection-95"
```

Comment: This almost works. I am getting a run-time error "3709" which is indicating that "The search key was not found in any record." Any advice?

Comment: check if all of your importing file have the same formatting/columns

Comment: I created a new import template using the import specs that I have and saved it. The new import template is what I am referencing in the code. The manual import works fine but the code doesn't. The data types for each column vary but I can't see that as being an issue. Also, I have more columns in the table than I do in the text docs so that I can manually add data to it. Could that be an issue? If so, why would the manual merge work but this one doesn't?

Comment: do a debug and see where it produces the error. check the template name, check the .xml before and after replacing the file path.