# Is there a way to make saved import dynamic through VBA in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

I have a database that needs to be passed around 5 users many times a day (MS 365). The database has 10 saved imports. But each user needs to update 3 of those with their own paths (those 3 files are always the same). It a hassle to do it multiple times a day. Due to certain restrictions from my employer, I must use the imports through saved imports only.

So is there a way to make it more dynamic through VBA?

For eg: inserting a combo box where if you chose user A his paths should be automatically updated in saved imports. Same with other users.

What I expect from the VBA code:

If you chose user A in combo box: the file paths in saved imports (for the same 3 files named let's say file1, file2 and file3) should automatically be updated to : C:\Users\A\documents\file1.txt, C:\Users\A\documents\file2.txt and C:\Users\A\documents\file3.txt.

If user B is chosen, the saved import should automatically be updated to: C:\Users\B\documents\file1.txt,
C:\Users\B\documents\file2.txt and C:\Users\B\documents\file3.txt.

Same should be the case for user C, D and E.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095869/modify-ms-access-importexportspecifications

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concatenate the folder string with Eviron(“UserName”)
Like:

```
    “C:\Users\” & Environ(“UserName”) & “…”
```