# Changed saved export specification on MS Access

Tags: ms-access, export, specifications

So, I'm having a hard time trying to add an extra field to an export using the DoCmd.TransferText function in Visual Basic. The Access file was written by a colleague that is no longer in touch with us at work, but he somehow managed to create an custom export Specification of a view WITH PARAMETERS, a thing I can't do because the export wizard tells me there are parameters missing, so no wizard help.

Following this thread:

[How can I modify a saved Microsoft Access 2007 or 2010 Import Specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143420/how-can-i-modify-a-saved-microsoft-access-2007-or-2010-import-specification)

I managed to change the specification info in the  MSysIMEXspecs and MSysIMEXColumns table following a certain answer but then when trying to run the TransferText it tells me that the data being exported is not the same as the one in Schema.ini ... Can someone provide any help?

Comment: You didn't try the first accepted answer of link? Alternatively, simply create a new export spec per your needs and save as over the previous one.

Comment: Yes I tried that but the wizard tells me there are missing parameters and I can't even get to the advanced part to save the new spec