# MS Access - Changed query to add more columns, but Macro running that query still exports only the previously-existing columns

Tags: ms-access

We have had a small MS Access mdb for years.
I added a few columns to a query which a Macro runs, and when the query is run separately it outputs the new columns.
The query is also run from a Macro, under an "ImportExportText" section when I look at the macro in design mode.
There's not much to that section - transfer type is "export fixed width", Specification Name is 1, File name is the full path to where the text file should be exported to, Has Field Names = No.

I run the macro, it outputs the txt file, but the txt file doesn't include the new columns.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The old export specification "1" still has only the old columns. You need to update it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143420/how-can-i-modify-a-saved-microsoft-access-2007-or-2010-import-specification

Comment: I will look into that, thanks Andre!