# DoCmd.Transfertext - How to modify Specification?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using a database that uses this code to import a CSV file into a table:

`DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "TA_Import", "TargetTable", xPath, True, ""`

"TA_Import" is the SpecificationName.  But because there's been a change to the format of our CSV file, I need to modify the specification. Where do I go to do that?

Comment: The "TA_Import" parameter is the name of the [specification that is stored in the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext) somewhere. Look for the name in the list of tables and other places to figure out how to modify it.

Comment: @PeterT I tried that.

Answer (score 3):

See
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-the-details-of-an-import-or-export-operation-as-a-specification-6b94e183-2b10-4333-a31a-001fe75321b5
for info on specifications I believe 2010 and onward.

And
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.importexportspecification

Also note:
If you create a specification and use the Advanced Option on the wizard, then the specification will be saved in system table MSysImexSpecs and the details will be stored in MSysImexColumns.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `SpecificationName`:

```vb
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", "TargetTable", xPath, True, ""
```

Comment: I don't understand what this will do. Will it prompt me for a specification? Does that let me change the one I have?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way, although I don't think its the *intended* way.

I started to follow [the steps here](https://datatofish.com/create-specification-name-access-2016/) to create a new specification. When I got to the step where you can name your specification, I noticed a button labeled "Specs...". Clicking that showed me a list of *existing* specifications, and the "Open" button gave me a dialog that let me modify it.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143420/how-can-i-modify-a-saved-microsoft-access-2007-or-2010-import-specification]