# How to save and rerun query steps when change input?

Tags: ms-access

I import 2 CSV files into MS Access and then apply some not complex queries based on content of both files to obtain a result table.

I've seen that the import/export steps can be saved, but is there a way to save the queries and get automatically the result table each time the input files change? Similar to what can be done in power query.

Comment: Import steps can be saved but that is not saving a query. Saved Import steps cannot be edited. However, can save an Import Specification and that can be edited. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-2016-how-do-we-edit-a-saved-import/d5202069-3e52-40cd-8694-2bd3760816f5 and https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1648301. However, changing the source is not an attribute that can be changed. If file structure is same, overwrite old file with new file using SaveAs.

Comment: Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143420/how-can-i-modify-a-saved-microsoft-access-2007-or-2010-import-specification

Comment: Again, if file structure remains same, overwrite old file with new file using SaveAs. Set links to files (one time) and action queries do not have to be modified because source names never change.

Comment: Thanks for the links you shared. So, if I maintain the name of source files, the import steps could be work with other files, but the queries I do in `Query Design` mode would work too? is there a button to refresh the whole process?

Comment: For example a query like this `SELECT File1.NUMBER, File1.VSW, File2.TYPE, File2.STATUS
FROM File1 INNER JOIN File2 ON File1.NUMBER = File2.[NUMBER]
WHERE (((File1.VSW)=5));` 
`

Comment: That's just a SELECT query, no action (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE). It could be data source for a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with importing volatile data sources but I will suggest what is probably simplest.

If file structure remains same, overwrite old files with new files (use same generic names). Set links to files (one time). Queries do not have to be modified because source names and structures never change.

Build code (macro or VBA) behind a form using a command button Click event to initiate whatever process is needed to manipulate data in linked tables. This could be calling UPDATE or INSERT action SQL or simply opening form or report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May you share if possible, an example macro to update with the button you say, I can do some basic code in Excel VBA, but I don't know anything of MS VBA in Access

Comment: That's a very broad ask and really getting beyond original question topic, which has been answered. There are several ways to update data in a table (starting with direct data entry/edit, i.e. typing). I am not sure anything I provided would useful until you learn more about programming in Access. VBA in Access is much the same as in Excel, just working with different objects - logic structures and language are same (I am aware of one minor exception). Suggest you do a little research and when you have code with specific issue, post a new question.

Comment: Access has another programming tool - macros. Macro in Access is not what you call a macro in Excel. Excel macro is just VBA. Macros are limited in what they can do compared to VBA but can be a quick start on programming in Access. I never have used - started programming in VBA from the get-go.